# Is it possible to use Android Jetpack Navigation with dynamic (at runtime determined) menu structure?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

My requirements are the following.
On app start the user enters an id/code based on which the app retrieves a list of custom menu items from a server which should be shown in a bottom navigation view.

As far as i know jetpack navigation relies on a static navigation graph. Is it possible to use jetpack navigation, more specifically the nav host fragment, without a static navigation graph or by programmatically building such a graph at runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called conditional navigation and that does not have to be completed programmatically.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional

Most people tend to create their nav-graphs in the navigation editor because it provides a visual guide.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately i think the conditional navigation of jetpack might not cover my use-case. Seems to me this is for "small" decisions in an otherwise static navigation graph like deciding between app start page or registration page when navigating from a login screen for example. Thanks anyway!